# Getting a form to POST in Javascript

Tags: javascript, http-post, forms

I'm populating a form in Javascript before sending it off, and thus need to post the form with javascript:

```
var url = "http://urltomyaction";
var myvar = "somedata";
var = oFormObject = document.forms['fileselectform'];
oFormObject.elements['myvar'].value = myvar;
oFormObject.action = url;
oFormObject.submit();
```

My issue is that I need to put the parameters in a POST, instead of encoding them in the URL, but this method results in a GET with the form parameters in the URL. What am I missing? How can I specify to POST?

Comment: What's the HTML for the `<form>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set its `method` attribute to `'POST'`, either in HTML:

```
<form ... method="POST" ...>...</form>
```

or in JavaScript:

```
oFormObject.method = 'POST';
```